# Node.js - Do I really need Visual Studio ? And Python 2.X or 3.X?

Tags: visual-studio, html, node.js, compiler-construction, websocket

trying to install websockets on windows Node.js.

I am getting native extensions require Visual Studio and Python.

My question is : Is it possible to take another compiler? Or do I really need VS (3,6GB) Download or are there alternatives, since I don´t want to download that huge amount.
Linux has GGC , I suppose.
And do I need Python 2.X or Python 3.X.

[image: Node.js]

Thanks for the replies.
Have a nice day.

Comment: unless your target platform is windows it might be easier to just install linux on vm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need visual studio in order to get the C++ compilers. You can pull down Visual Studio 2010 Express [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2010-express), which is a much smaller download (694MB). For python, you'll need 2.6 or 2.7 as described on the [node.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation) wiki on github.

Another alternate is to simply use the binaries already [supplied](http://nodejs.org/download/) by the node.js team. If you go this route, you won't have to compile the source yourself. From what I can tell, node should already support websockets. See a tutorial on how to set up a server using websockets [here](http://cosmi.nu/html5-websockets-node-js-and-socket-io-on-windows/62/).

Comment: VS is really needed for the MS VC++ compiler, not .NET.

Comment: Also, notice that Node itself is already running, probably from the binaries.  He's having problems during a npm install, where native extensions have to be built from source.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the clarifications. Updating my answer to reflect.

Comment: Can't these things be delivered in a pre compiled form?

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ws-compatible JS-only modules which don't require C++ runtime/node/V8 headers/Waf/Python

Install node.js from [pre-built package](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) (~5mb download, includes npm), then do `npm install sockjs` (sockjs implements websockets server as one of available transports). Then connect using HTML5 webscockets client or using [sockjs-client library](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client).

[List of other modules on Node.js wiki](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Modules#wiki-ws-ajax)

Comment: where do i get a pre-build package?