# Facing error in Ionic installation

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

i have resolved all the dependencies for installing ionic framework,
setup Python env variable, when i am running "npm install -g cordova ionic"
now i am getting this error.

```
MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe".
 To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visua
l Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it
is installed elsewhere.  [C:\Users\My User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\ionic\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\gaze\
build\binding.sln]
npm http GETgyp https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.4.0
 ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_mo
dules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:
12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\nod
e_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\My User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\n
ode_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\gaze
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.13
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.2
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Does it really require .NET framework, i didnt find anything like in its documentation.
need help.

Answer (score 1):

Specially for **Windows** users the Ionic Team has developed the **Ionic Box**. Take a look here: http://ionicframework.com/blog/ionic-vagrant-android/

> **Ionic Box**, an all-in-one project for setting up hybrid development
>   environments more quickly and easily.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic doesn't need it directly but Cordova certainly. Have a look to this thread, it will certainly help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12426368/646162

Answer (score 0):

Windows Solution:

Don't forget to install other dependencies before installing ionic http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html

1) Uninstall Node from Control Panel

2) Restart PC

3) Download (MSI Installer) older version of Node from http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.38/ and for 64bit http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.38/x64/

4) Install Node version 0.10.38

5) npm install -g cordova

6) npm install -g ionic

Done!