# Can I use Mongodb in node.js without Visual Studio on Win 7?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to use mongoose or mongodb in nodejs without having installed visual Studio? It seems that bson need it.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: If you're running code that must be compiled then you have to have VC++ compiler installed.

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425850/node-js-do-i-really-need-visual-studio-and-python-2-x-or-3-x

Comment: I try to use mean.js and think it's required.

Comment: See the linked question and download/install VC++ express.

Comment: Okay, then I try that. I haven't admin rights so I will see if I can do that.